# How to get state of checkbox group when page is load

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

i'm create one group of checkbox for load calendars on fullcalendar, but i can't load previous state of checkboxes when page is loaded.

- my Controller

  ```
  public function render()
  {        
   $this->agendas = AgendaAgendas::select('agenda', 'id', 'ver')->where('entidade', '=', $this->entidade)->get();

   return view('livewire.agenda')->layout('layouts.clear');
  }
  ```
- My laravel blade

  ```
  @foreach ($agendas as $key => $agenda)
   <div class="mt-1 d-flex justify-content-between p-1" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#f0f0f0';"
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';">
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <label class="inline-flex items-center" for="vagenda.{{ $agenda->id }}">
            <input name="{{ $agenda->id }}[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $agenda->id }}" 
                wire:model="selectAgenda.{{ $agenda->id }}"
                {{ $agenda->show == 'S' ? 'checked' : '' }}
                id="vagenda.{{ $agenda->id }}" class="form-check-input text-green-500 h-6 w-6">
            <span class="ml-3 text-sm">{{ $agenda->agenda }}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
     <div><small><span class="badge bg-danger" role="button" wire:click="deleteAgenda({{ $agenda->id }})"><iclass="fa fa-times"></i></span></small></div></div>
  @endforeach
  ```

As we can see above I'm trying to use this item to keep the item checked

```
  {{ $agenda->show == 'S' ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

But the checkbox's don't appear checked. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I deal with checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" wire:change="selectAgenda({{ $agenda->id }})"
  {{ $agenda->show == 'S' ? 'checked' : '' }} id="vagenda.{{ $agenda->id }}" class="form-check-input text-green-500 h-6 w-6">
```

and in the component handle the checkbox changes through selectAgenda method